# A system that intergates with Tibco spotfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotfire

I want to develop a system that integrates with Tibco Spotfire and is able to Retrieve Visualizations rendered by Spotfire and expose them for WYSIWYG manipulation. Is this possible?
If so someone please offer guidance. I want to use C# and ASP.NET

Comment: I wonder what exact functionalities you would like to get by your system. What exact manipulations. But probably it is sth currently provided as Web Author tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotfire Web Player (which I assume you refer to) is not built in this way - in its current implementation it is more like a remote desktop session to the desktop Spotfire application (if you replace the remote desktop technology with html and javascript).

It simply is not built to be able to grab pieces of the UI for reuse in other contexts. The closest you can do is host the entire web player UI in an iframe and use the [javascript API](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/API.aspx?API=wpl%2fhtml%2fN_spotfire_webPlayer.htm) for client-side interactions. By creating single-visualization pages and removing all chrome (toolbars etc) you can get to something that appears to be a single visualization on a page, but it's really just a hack.

Answer (score 3):

1. first load the javascriptapi for handling client interactions

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domainname/SpotfireWeb/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=3.1" > </script>
   ```
2. add the code for adding the spotfire template to web page
   create a javascript file in your project with the code below:

   ```
   function addPlayer()
   {
       var fileInfo = new FileInformation(SpotfireVisualizationPath,SpotfireVisualizationName,SpotfireParameter, '');

       var customization = new spotfire.webPlayer.Customization();
       customization.showCustomizableHeader = false;
       customization.showToolBar = false;
       customization.showClose = false;
       customization.showTopHeader = false;

       if (app != null)
       {
           app.close();
       }

       app = new spotfire.webPlayer.Application(SpotfireWebPlayerURL, customization);
       app.open(fileInfo.path, 'SpotfireContainer', fileInfo.parameters);

   }
   ```